# java.sql.SQLException: expection being thrown for SQOOP import

Tags: mysql, hadoop, jdbc, mapreduce, sqoop

When i'm trying to store table stored in mysql database into my HDFS using

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://hostname1.com/mydb --username user1 --password pwd1 --table emp1;

I'm getting following exception:

```
Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.3-1.cdh5.4.3.p0.6/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
15/07/24 22:48:54 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.4.3
15/07/24 22:48:54 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
15/07/24 22:48:55 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
15/07/24 22:48:55 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
15/07/24 22:48:55 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `emp1` AS t LIMIT 1
15/07/24 22:48:55 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error reading from database: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@2d749418 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@2d749418 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:934)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:931)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkForOutstandingStreamingData(MysqlIO.java:2735)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1899)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2569)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1524)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMaxBytesPerChar(ConnectionImpl.java:3003)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.getMaxBytesPerCharacter(Field.java:602)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.getPrecision(ResultSetMetaData.java:445)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:286)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
15/07/24 22:48:55 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

My sqoop version is Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.4.3 and mysql-connector version is  5.1.31.

Any help in fixing my exception?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like Sqoop enables streaming result sets (`setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`) in the MySQL driver. When streaming result sets the MySQL connection cannot execute any other queries. You'll need to find out how you can prevent Sqoop from doing that

Comment: Give table name in caps(EMP1), that might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this version of Sqoop there is some problem with fetch size which is being set to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (-2147483648) in `MySQLManager` class in `/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/manager/MySQLManager.java`. The default value set is 0 which is being overridden in this class. Due to this the resultset associated to the row are not releasing the lock and thus the error message. See below code from Sqoop source code:

```
@Override
  protected void initOptionDefaults() {
    if (options.getFetchSize() == null) {
      LOG.info("Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.");
      options.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);      //this line is causing the error
    } else if (
        !options.getFetchSize().equals(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        && !options.getFetchSize().equals(0)) {
      LOG.info("Argument '--fetch-size " + options.getFetchSize()
          + "' will probably get ignored by MySQL JDBC driver.");
      // see also
      // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en
      //                       /connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html
    }
  }
```

To solve this error, remove the above `initOptionDefaults` method from the MySQLManager class of the source code of your Sqoop version.

**REF:**https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1400

Comment: Thanks Sai for your reply.Issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sqoop Client Java API, you can specify the fetch size explicitly in the SqoopOptions as :

```
private static SqoopOptions SqoopOptions = new SqoopOptions();
 SqoopOptions.setFetchSize(1000);
```